# Generic function to get row count in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, rowcount

I want to write a generic function where I can pass a worksheet and it can return the row count in that worksheet. I am getting a type mismatch error

```vb
Public numberofRowsinWorksheet As Integer

Sub Routine1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet Name")
    numberofRowsinWorksheet = getRowCount(ws)
    MsgBox (numberofRowsinWorsheet)
End Sub

Function getRowCount(sheetName As Worksheet) As Integer
        Dim getNumberofRows As Integer
        getNumberofRows = .Range("A2", Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End Function
```

Comment: did you know you can put breakpoints in VBA? Learning to do that will pay massive dividends to you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting your worksheet object and worksheet names mixed up, your function return type should be Long, and your `.Range` doesn't refer back to anything.

Just do this:

```
Function getRowCount(ws As Worksheet) As Long
  getRowCount = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

An alternative would be this:

```
Function getRowCount(ws As Worksheet) As Long
  With ws  
    getRowCount = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  End With
End Function
```

You can also make it generic to optionally include which column you are using:

```
Function getRowCount(ws As Worksheet, Optional sCol as String = "A") As Long
  getRowCount = ws.Range(sCol & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

<sub>Not really sure why you would need to make such a simple one line code a function, but there you go.</sub>

Comment: I made a `funtion` similiar to this with 2 input `parameters`, being, `worksheet` & `type of row` which equals last used row or first blank row. Persoanlly I think it makes code a lot neater.